# Curl error (2) when trying to connect with sftp

Tags: curl, sftp

I have confirmed that I can login via Telnet

```
$ telnet ftp.domain.com 990 
Trying xx.xxx.xxx.xx... 
Connected to ftp.domain.com. Escape character is '^]'.
```

I am getting the following error when trying to connect with sftp

```
curl: (2) Failure establishing ssh session
```

Doing the following

```
curl -u user sftp://ftp.domain.com:990/ToFile/file.csv
```

I enter the password then it waits and I get the error

I checked to see if fips was disabled

```
cat /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled
0
```

I also tried the following:

```
$ sftp -P 990 user@ftp.domain.com
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

I then tried the following:

```
$ sftp -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -P 990 user@ftp.domain.com
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host 
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: are you sure it's really sftp you're doing and not simply... ftp?

Comment: I have confirmed I can connect from my local so it appears to be something with the Amazon server

Answer (score 1):

Your service is probably using pure `ftp`, but connecting to something you don't know is usually receipt for bad question. Can you connect using `ftp`:

```
ftp ftp.domain.com 990
curl -u user ftp://ftp.domain.com:990/ToFile/file.csv
```

SFTP is usually running on port `22` over `ssh`. Are you able to connect to the server over `ssh`? What is in your `sshd_config`? Your errors are saying that there is not running `ssh` on the tried port.

Comment: I have confirmed I can connect from my local so it is my server (AWS AMI)